# Как внедрить свой скрипт в страницу браузера?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Браузер FF, в нем открыта и постоянно обновляется страница (не знаю spa это или нет). Как можно внедрить в это окно браузера свой скрипт? Возможно вообще такое?

Comment: Что происходить то должно? Клик, какой-нить, например, можно имитировать

Comment: @xaja: хочу себе качалку музыки сделать.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/vkontakteru-downloader/ или просто плагин )

Comment: @xaja: а можно спросить, почему Вы посоветовали мне плагин для вконтакте, я где ВК упомянул?

Comment: только про читал другой вопрос именно по vkontakte и в голове одно на другое наложилось, сорри )

Comment: @xaja: да ничего, у самого тоже бывает..

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24338/discussion-between-xaja-and-vas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть подойдет [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) - расширение, которое позволяет выполнять пользовательские скрипты на сайтах.

Comment: Или более легковесный метод - [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) - работает даже без расширений, но требует ручных действий (нажать на закладку) после открытия страницы.